# How to do the the filter with this design on react native?

Tags: react-native

I have to design specific filters. But i absolutly don't know how to call this sort of filter to find some documentation ?

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

for this design, you can use [this library](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider). and for the js side, you can use the filter method on your arrays. for more information about the way of using the filter method [follow this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Notify me if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't complete understood your question but I believe you might want to know how to achieve this UI where You can use single slider and also Multi slider

You can check [React Native Multi Slider](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider) and also read this article [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/a-clean-react-native-multi-slider-for-android-and-ios-using-hooks-3bd6c587b381)